# GPL software with commercial use exception

Tags: gpl, commercial, freeware

PortableApps.com Launcer stated that:

> License: Free / Open Source (GPL) with exceptions for freeware and free open source. Commercial use by contacting PortableApps.com
>   http://portableapps.com/apps/development/portableapps.com_launcher

All apps from portableapps.com is made by portableapps.com launcher, for example http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/ultradefrag-portable stated that

> Source Code: PortableApps.com Launcher, UltraDefrag

My intention is to use application bundled from portableapps.com on corporate or bussiness environtment.
Does it mean that any application bundled from portableapps.com is prohibited in commercial usage without contacting PortableApps.com?

---

And also, PortableApps.com Installer also stated that:

> License: Free / Open Source (GPL) with exceptions for freeware and free open source. Commercial use by contacting PortableApps.com.
>   http:// portableapps.com/apps/development/portableapps.com_installer

My question is different from this question [Are all GPL Licensed projects free to use for commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/are-all-gpl-licensed-projects-free-to-use-for-commercial-use) because of the license statement "Commercial use by contacting PortableApps.com"

Comment: @congusbongus I don't think so because of this statement "Commercial use by contacting PortableApps.com"

Comment: The question might be _slightly_ different but the answer is the same. There is no prohibition on commercial use in the GPL, nor is there in any open source license. Additional restrictions on the GPL are not enforceable.